# Using pt-online-schema-change within a migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, percona

I'm currently building a new application which runs on an existing database - which is already in production. This new app is built in Laravel 4 and has a few migrations to make schema changes that are required.

Requirements are to use Percona Toolkits `pt-online-schema-change` to issue schema changes, however I cannot find anywhere how to use this from within a migration - just the standard CLI interface. I need some way to tie together the schema change within the migration and `pt-online-schema-change`.

I don't want to loose all the benefits that come with writing migrations or using the Laravel schema builder. I was hoping there is a simple way I'm not seeing to use Percona Toolkit within them. I have thought of using `exec()` but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

When "Googling" periodically over the past few weeks, I could not find anything which resembles using Percona Toolkit within a migration. Surely this is a problem that has been solved already?

If my approach is flawed, please tell me! :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably will be able to execute it like this in your migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    exec('pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD COLUMN c1 INT" D=sakila,t=actor', $output, $return);

    if ( ! $return) {
        throw \Exception('Error migrating '.__FILE__);
    }
}
```